# Shared iAPs/subscription among iPhone, iPad and macOS Catalyst apps?

Tags: ios, macos, ipad, subscription, mac-catalyst

I look around but could not find an answer. If my iOS/iPadOS and macCatalyst are based on a subscription or contain in-app purchases, is it possible to have the same subscription for the 3 apps, or restore the purchase for all 3 apps? As in, when the user subscribes on iPad, can the subscription carry over to the macCatalyst app, using only Apple's technologies?

Answer (score 0):

Tested this question, from different applications come different recipes from the same ICloud. Merge failed.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2020, this is now possible using Universal Purchases:

https://developer.apple.com/support/universal-purchase

> Distribute iOS, iPadOS, watchOS, macOS, and tvOS versions of your app as a universal purchase to let customers easily enjoy your app and in‑app purchases across platforms. They’ll only need to purchase once on the App Store.

This seems to rely on the use of the 'use iOS bundle identifier' to make sure the bundle ids are the same. With Catalyst apps released under xCode 11.3 or earlier there is additional work involved to move them over to a single bundle id